# Alternative to Union for inserting data from three tables into one temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I am trying to insert data from three separate tables into one temp table. The three tables mostly consist of the same columns but there is no link between them (i.e. no link between tblOne and tblTwo in the example below). I am able to get the result I'm hoping for using the following code but I am thinking there must be a more efficient way that I am not using.

```
DECLARE @ExampleTable TABLE(Column1 INT, Column2 INT, Column3 INT, Column4 NVARCHAR(50), Column5 DATETIME, Column6 decimal(19,8))
INSERT INTO @ExampleTable
SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2, A.Column3, A.Column4, Aa.Column5, A.Column6
FROM    tblOne AS A INNER JOIN
            tblOneJoin AS Aa ON Aa.ID = A.ExampleColumn
WHERE   ClauseColumn IN (2,3)
UNION 
SELECT B.Column1, B.Column2, B.Column3, B.Column4, Bb.Column5, B.Column6
FROM    tblTwo AS B INNER JOIN
            tblTwoJoin AS Bb ON Bb.ID = B.ExampleColumn
WHERE   ClauseColumn IN (2,3)
UNION 
SELECT C.Column1, C.Column2, C.Column3, C.Column4, Cc.Column5, C.Column6
FROM    tblThree AS C INNER JOIN
            tblThreeJoin AS Cc ON Cc.ID = C.ExampleColumn
WHERE   ClauseColumn IN (2,3)
```

Am I right in thinking there is a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hoping for, but if you need data from 3 tables then a union is the way to do it. As an aside its best practice when inserting data to list the columns you are inserting into. Otherwise what you have seems fine.

Comment: Also, it might be more efficient to perform the three inserts separately, since `UNION` will add distinct sorts to the overall result. If you don't actually _need_ that to happen, performing three separate inserts will be easier on the optimizer and also potentially easier on the transaction log. At the same time, don't prematurely optimize. Is there a performance problem now? If not, focus on other things, IMHO. You can spend your entire career contemplating whether there is some other way to discover doing something slightly more efficiently, and be not much further ahead.

Comment: Oh, yes, definitely use `UNION ALL` not `UNION` - de-duping the results for a `UNION` can be a performance hit.

Comment: The "better" way would be to merge the 3 tables, which clearly have similar uses, into 1 table with perhaps an extra column to indicate the type (ie their source table).

Comment: `"with perhaps an extra column"` : Do you want to have this extra column in all rows @Bohemian just to make your life simpler?  If that extra column is a nullable fixed length data type will you be OK with have this extra space in each row. I am sorry but without more information based on what we have here, this sound to me like an awful idea. Merging the tables might be good idea as part of redesigning the system but not "just add extra column"... I agree with Dale K

Comment: The only efficiency for the database is to use indexes.  Specific to that query would be a filtered index that has ClauseColumn IN (2,3) for all 3 queries.  If you're worried about the amount of code written then you can create a View to select those union-ed datasets then insert the select of the view into the temp table.  That would at least avoid having to write the full thing out each time.